# Webpack empty first module

Tags: webpack, survivejs

I start learning webpack and reading survive.js book (http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/getting_started/) for this. But I can't understand one moment.

When I try build first example – I have one chunk more that in book. 
Books build log:

````
```> webpack
Hash: e02f97146a15a8a5c3a9
Version: webpack 1.8.4
Time: 44ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.74 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./app/main.js 115 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./app/component.js 134 bytes {0} [built]```
````

My build log

````
```λ webpack --display-chunks --display-reasons
Hash: 0028e8ab537ae7e91068
Version: webpack 1.10.5
Time: 64ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.88 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 323 bytes [rendered]
    [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./app/main.js 151 bytes {0} [built]
        single entry D:\Freelance\examples\react-learning\survivejs\app\main [0] multi main
    [2] ./app/component.js 144 bytes {0} [built]
        cjs require ./component [1] ./app/main.js 1:16-38
```
````

Can you help me to understand why I have `[0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]`? How I can remove this and have two modules in my final file?

Comment: Hi, author here. That sounds a little weird. Can you join me at https://gitter.im/survivejs/webpack_react ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had some outdated print at the book. Yours is correct!

Given these tools move so fast it's easy to get outdated. The next edition will contain correct output.